# \includegraphics Dimension Too Large

Tags: overleaf, includegraphics, dimensions

I was trying to insert a .pdf image in my Latex Document and I was getting the dimension too large error. But I found out that Latex automatically resizes the image to the max it can support. After that the image was not aligning properly and covering the text and was going to the top right corner of the page.
[image]

Here is the code:

```
    \begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{Images/cifar10_report_1.pdf}
        \caption{Generated samples on CIFAR 10 (32 x 32 Images)}
        \label{fig4.1}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

I was not able to find any solutions to this. I shall be grateful if the community could help.

Comment: Welcome. // At least two problems here: a) We can't copy and compile (!) your code, as imprtant parts are missing; b) we can't have any idea about your image. // Do you get the same result when you replace it by `example-image` from the graohicx package?

Comment: latex only scales the image if you specify that. Here you have `width=0.6\textwidth`  which is presumably too large.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Even if I choose width=0.1\textwidth, I get the same dimension too large error

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document, which reproduce your problem. For example to something like `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{Generated samples on CIFAR 10 (32 x 32 Images)}
\label{fig4.1}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}` (which works fine).

Comment: @MS-SPO No I don't get the issue with example-image. It works perfectly fine with it

Comment: Than you have a problem with image, which is unknown to us. Without providing MWE (Minimal Working Example), which reproduce your problem, we can't help you.

Comment: @Zarko I tried with the code you gave. Same Issue Persists there too

Comment: @Zarko Is there a way with which I can share the image with you guys?

Comment: Firs examine your image yourself. Is it visible in pdf reader? Does it has a  white borders? How it is composed? Any image in `pfd` format should scale to prescribed width (that not means that sub images will be well visible). Image you can show in some free accessible site.

Comment: How large is the original pdf?